# How to make a binary tree zipper an instance of Comonad?

Tags: haskell, zipper, comonad

I want to make a binary tree zipper an instance of comonad, but I can't figure out how to implement `duplicate` properly.

Here is my attempt:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}
import Data.Function
import Control.Arrow
import Control.Comonad

data BinTree a
    = Leaf a
    | Branch a (BinTree a) (BinTree a)
      deriving (Functor, Show, Eq)

data Dir = L | R
    deriving (Show, Eq)

-- an incomplete binary tree, aka data context
data Partial a = Missing Dir (BinTree a) a
    deriving (Show, Eq, Functor)

-- BTZ for BinTree Zipper
newtype BTZ a = BTZ { getBTZ :: ([Partial a], BinTree a) }
    deriving (Show, Eq)

instance Functor BTZ where
    fmap f (BTZ (cs,t)) = BTZ (map (fmap f) cs, fmap f t)

-- | replace every node label with the zipper focusing on that node
dup :: BinTree a -> BinTree (BTZ a)
dup (Leaf v) = Leaf (BTZ ([], Leaf v))
dup t@(Branch v tl tr) = Branch (BTZ ([],t)) tlZ trZ
    where
        tlZ = fmap (BTZ . first (++ [Missing L tr v]) . getBTZ) (dup tl)
        trZ = fmap (BTZ . first (++ [Missing R tl v]) . getBTZ) (dup tr)

-- | extract root label
rootVal :: BinTree a -> a
rootVal (Leaf v) = v
rootVal (Branch v _ _) = v

-- | move zipper focus around
goUp, goLeft, goRight :: BTZ a -> BTZ a

goUp (BTZ ([], _)) = error "already at root"
goUp (BTZ (Missing wt t2 v:xs, t1)) = case wt of
    L -> BTZ (xs, Branch v t1 t2)
    R -> BTZ (xs, Branch v t2 t1)

goLeft z = let (cs,t) = getBTZ z in
    case t of
      Leaf _ -> error "already at leaf"
      Branch v t1 t2 -> BTZ (Missing L t2 v:cs, t1)

goRight z = let (cs,t) = getBTZ z in
    case t of
      Leaf _ -> error "already at leaf"
      Branch v t1 t2 -> BTZ (Missing R t1 v:cs, t2)

instance Comonad BTZ where
    extract (BTZ (_,t)) =
        case t of
          Leaf v -> v
          Branch v _ _ -> v

    duplicate z@(BTZ (cs, bt)) = case bt of
        Leaf _ -> BTZ (csZ, Leaf z) -- extract . duplicate = id
        Branch v tl tr ->
            -- for each subtree, use "dup" to build zippers,
            -- and attach the current focusing root(bt) and rest of the data context to it
            let tlZ = fmap (BTZ . first (++Missing L tr v :cs) . getBTZ) (dup tl)
                trZ = fmap (BTZ . first (++Missing R tl v :cs) . getBTZ) (dup tr)
             in BTZ (csZ, Branch z tlZ trZ)
        where
            -- go up and duplicate, we'll have a "BTZ (BTZ a)"
            -- from which we can grab "[Partial (BTZ a)]" out
            -- TODO: not sure if it works
            upZippers = take (length cs-1) . tail $ iterate goUp z
            csZ = fmap (head . fst . getBTZ . duplicate) upZippers

main :: IO ()
main = do
   let tr :: BTZ Int
       tr = rootVal $ dup (Branch 1 (Leaf 2) (Branch 3 (Leaf 4) (Leaf 5)))
       equalOnTr :: Eq a => (BTZ Int -> a) -> (BTZ Int -> a) -> Bool
       equalOnTr = (==) `on` ($ tr)
   print $ (extract . duplicate)      `equalOnTr` id
   print $ (fmap extract . duplicate) `equalOnTr` id
   print $ (duplicate . duplicate)    `equalOnTr` (fmap duplicate . duplicate)
```

Some explanation:

- `BinTree a` is the binary tree data type and each tree node contains a label.
- `Partial a` is a binary tree with either left or right subtree. A stack of `Partial a`
  in my code plays the role of data context.
- `BTZ` stands for the `BinTree` zipper, which I want to make an instance of `Comonad`, it consists of a data context and the focusing subtree.

To make it an instance of `Comonad`, my plan is to implement `extract` and `duplicate`, and verify if the comonad properties hold by taking some random binary trees.

The `extract` is straightforward, just taking the focusing subtree out.

Function `dup` serves as an auxiliary function that replaces each node label
with the tree zipper focusing on that node.

For `duplicate z`, the node label needs to be `z` itself so that `extract . duplicate == id` holds. For non-leaf nodes, I use `dup` to deal with their subtrees as if they have no parents, and the current focus of `z` and the rest of the data context gets appended to these zippers afterwards.

So far the first two comonad properties are satisfied (`extract . duplicate = id` and `fmap extract . duplicate`), but I have no idea what to do with the data context. What I currently do is taking the zipper `z` and keep going up. Along the way we take the top of each data context stack to build the new data context stack, which sounds right to be and also is of the correct type (`[Partial (BTZ a)]`. But my approach cannot satisfy the third law.

Given the data type definition of binary tree zipper above,
is it possible to make it an instance of Comonad?
If the answer is yes, is there something wrong with my approach?

Comment: Two things are not equal. Compare the output of `print $ (duplicate . duplicate) tr` and `print $ (fmap duplicate . duplicate) tr`. The latter exhibits `*** Exception: Prelude.head: empty list
`.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In the differential calculus, Leibniz's notation causes less confusion than Newton's because it is explicit about the variable with respect to which we differentiate. Contexts in things are given by differentiation, so we must take care what is being contextualized. Here, there are two notions of "substructure" at work: *subtrees* and *elements*. They each have different (but related) notions of "context" and hence of "zipper", where a zipper is the pair of a thing and its context.

Your `BTZ` type is presented as the notion of zipper for *subtrees*. However, the zipper comonadic construction works on zippers for *elements*: `extract` means "give element here"; `duplicate` means "decorate each element with its context". So you need element contexts. Confusingly, for these binary trees, element zippers and subtree zippers are isomorphic, but that is for a very particular reason (namely that they form a cofree comonad).

Generally, element- and subtree-zippers differ, e.g., for lists. If we start by building the element-zipper comonad for lists, we are less likely to get lost when we come back to trees. Let me try also to fill in a bit more of the general picture, for others as well as yourself.

#### Sublist contexts

The *sublist*-contexts for `[a]` are just given by `[a]`, being the list of elements we pass by on the way out from the sublist to the whole list. The sublist context for `[3,4]` in `[1,2,3,4]` is `[2,1]`. Subnode contexts for recursive data are always lists representing what you see on the path from the node to the root. The type of each step is given by the partial derivative of the formula for one node of data with respect to the recursive variable. So here

```
[a] = t where             -- t is the recursive variable standing for [a]
  t = 1 + a*t             -- lists of a are either [] or an (a : t) pair
∂/∂t (1 + a*t) = a        -- that's one step on a path from node to root
sublist contexts are [a]  -- a list of such steps
```

So a sublist-zipper is a pair

```
data LinLZ a = LinLZ
  {  subListCtxt  :: [a]
  ,  subList      :: [a]
  }
```

We can write the function which plugs a sublist back into its context, reversing back up the path

```
plugLinLZ :: LinLZ a -> [a]
plugLinLZ (LinLZ { subListCtxt = [],      subList = ys})  = ys
plugLinLZ (LinLZ { subListCtxt = x : xs,  subList = ys})
  = plugLinLZ (LinLZ { subListCtxt = xs,  subList = x : ys})
```

But we can't make `LinLZ` a `Comonad`, because (for example) from

```
LinLZ { subListCtxt = [], subList = [] }
```

we can't `extract` an *element* (an `a` from `LinLZ a`), only a sublist.

#### List Element Contexts

A list *element* context is a pair of lists: the elements before the element in focus, and the elements after it. An element context in a recursive structure is always a pair: first give the subnode-context for the subnode where the element is stored, then give the context for the element in its node. We get the element-in-its-node context by differentiating the formula for a node with respect to the variable which stands for elements.

```
[a] = t where             -- t is the recursive variable standing for [a]
  t = 1 + a*t             -- lists of a are either [] or an (a : t) pair
∂/∂a (1 + a*t) = t = [a]  -- the context for the head element is the tail list
```

So an element context is given by a pair

```
type DL a =
  (  [a]     -- the sublist context for the node where the element is
  ,  [a]     -- the tail of the node where the element is
  )
```

and an element zipper is given by pairing such a context with the element "in the hole".

```
data ZL a = ZL
  {  this :: a
  ,  between :: DL a
  }  deriving (Show, Eq, Functor)
```

You can turn such a zipper back into a list (going "out" from an element) by first reconstituting the sublist where the element sits, giving us a sublist zipper, then plugging the sublist into its sublist-context.

```
outZL :: ZL a -> [a]
outZL (ZL { this = x, between = (zs, xs) })
  = plugLinLZ (LinLZ { subListCtxt = zs, subList = x : xs })
```

#### Putting each element into context

Given a list, we can pair each element up with its context. We get the list of ways we can "go into" one of the elements. We start like this,

```
into :: [a] -> [ZL a]
into xs = moreInto (LinLZ { subListCtxt = [], subList = xs })
```

but the real work is done by the helper function which works on a list-in-context.

```
moreInto :: LinLZ a -> [ZL a]
moreInto (LinLZ { subListCtxt = _,   subList = [] })      = []
moreInto (LinLZ { subListCtxt = zs,  subList = x : xs })
  =  ZL { this = x, between = (zs, xs) } 
  :  moreInto (LinLZ { subListCtxt = x : zs,  subList = xs })
```

Notice that the output echoes the shape of the current `subList`. Also, the zipper in `x`'s place has
`this = x`. Also, the generating zipper for decorating `xs` has `subList = xs` and the correct context,
recording that we have moved past `x`. Testing,

```
into [1,2,3,4] =
  [  ZL {this = 1, between = ([],[2,3,4])}
  ,  ZL {this = 2, between = ([1],[3,4])}
  ,  ZL {this = 3, between = ([2,1],[4])}
  ,  ZL {this = 4, between = ([3,2,1],[])}
  ]
```

#### Comonadic structure for list element zippers

We've seen how to go out from an element, or into one of the available elements. The comonadic structure tells us how to move between elements, either staying where we are, or moving to one of the others.

```
instance Comonad ZL where
```

The `extract` gives us the element we're visiting.

```
  extract = this
```

To `duplicate` a zipper, we replace the current element `x` with the whole current zipper `zl` (whose `this = x`)...

```
  duplicate zl@(ZL { this = x, between = (zs, ys) }) = ZL
    {  this = zl
```

...and we work our way through the context, showing how to refocus at each element. Our existing `moreInto` lets us move inward, but we must also move `outward`...

```
    ,  between =
         (  outward (LinLZ { subListCtxt = zs, subList = x : ys })
         ,  moreInto (LinLZ { subListCtxt = x : zs, subList = ys })
         )
    }
```

...which involves travelling back along the context, moving elements into the sublist, as follows

```
    where
      outward (LinLZ { subListCtxt = [], subList = _ }) = []
      outward (LinLZ { subListCtxt = z : zs, subList = ys })
        =  ZL { this = z, between = (zs, ys) }
        :  outward (LinLZ { subListCtxt = zs, subList = z : ys })
```

So we get

```
duplicate ZL {this = 2, between = ([1],[3,4])}
  = ZL
  {  this = ZL {this = 2, between = ([1],[3,4])}
  ,  between =
     (  [  ZL {this = 1, between = ([],[2,3,4])}  ]
     ,  [  ZL {this = 3, between = ([2,1],[4])}
        ,  ZL {this = 4, between = ([3,2,1],[])}
        ]
     )
  }
```

where `this` is "staying at `2`" and we are `between` "moving to `1`" and "moving to `3` or moving to `4`".

So, the comonadic structure shows us how we can move between different *elements* located inside a list. The sublist structure plays a key role in finding the nodes where the elements are, but the zipper structure `duplicate`d is an *element* zipper.

So what about trees?

#### Digression: labelled trees are comonads already

Let me refactor your type of binary trees to bring out some structure. Literally, let us pull the element which labels a leaf or a fork out as a common factor. Let us also isolate the functor (`TF`) which explains this leaf-or-fork subtree structure.

```
data TF t = Leaf | Fork (t, t) deriving (Show, Eq, Functor)
data BT a = a :& TF (BT a) deriving (Show, Eq, Functor)
```

That is, every tree node has a label, whether it is a leaf or a fork.

Wherever we have the structure that every node has a label and a blob of substructures, we have a comonad: the *cofree* *comonad*. Let me refactor a little more, abstracting out `TF`...

```
data CoFree f a = a :& f (CoFree f a) deriving (Functor)
```

...so we have a general `f` where we had `TF` before. We can recover our specific trees.

```
data TF t = Leaf | Fork (t, t) deriving (Show, Eq, Functor)
type BT = CoFree TF
deriving instance Show a => Show (BT a)
deriving instance Eq a => Eq (BT a)
```

And now, once for all, we can give the cofree comonad construction. As every subtree has a root element, every element can be decorated with the tree whose root it is.

```
instance Functor f => Comonad (CoFree f) where
  extract   (a :& _)     = a                         -- extract root element
  duplicate t@(a :& ft)  = t :& fmap duplicate ft    -- replace root element by whole tree
```

Let's have an example

```
aTree =
  0 :& Fork
  (  1 :& Fork
     (  2 :& Leaf
     ,  3 :& Leaf
     )
  ,  4 :& Leaf
  )

duplicate aTree =
  (0 :& Fork (1 :& Fork (2 :& Leaf,3 :& Leaf),4 :& Leaf)) :& Fork
  (  (1 :& Fork (2 :& Leaf,3 :& Leaf)) :& Fork
     (  (2 :& Leaf) :& Leaf
     ,  (3 :& Leaf) :& Leaf
     )
  ,  (4 :& Leaf) :& Leaf
  )
```

See? Each element has been paired with its subtree!

Lists do not give rise to a cofree comonad, because not every node has an element: specifically, `[]` has no element. In a cofree comonad, there is always an element where you are, and you can see further down into the tree structure, *but not further up*.

**In an element zipper comonad, there is always an element where you are, and you can see both up and down.**

#### Subtree and element contexts in binary trees

Algebraically

```
d/dt (TF t) = d/dt (1 + t*t) = 0 + (1*t + t*1)
```

so we may define

```
type DTF t = Either ((), t) (t, ())
```

saying that a subtree inside the "blob of substructures" is either on the left or the right. We can check that "plugging in" works.

```
plugF :: t -> DTF t -> TF t
plugF  t  (Left   ((), r))  = Fork (t, r)
plugF  t  (Right  (l, ()))  = Fork (l, t)
```

If we instantiate `t` and pair up with the node label, we get one step of subtree context

```
type BTStep a = (a, DTF (BT a))
```

which is isomorphic to `Partial` in the question.

```
plugBTinBT :: BT a -> BTStep a -> BT a
plugBTinBT t (a, d) = a :& plugF t d
```

So, a *subtree*-context for one `BT a` inside another is given by `[BTStep a]`.

But what about an *element* context? Well, every element labels some subtree, so we should record both that subtree's context and the rest of the tree labelled by the element.

```
data DBT a = DBT
  {  below  :: TF (BT a)    -- the rest of the element's node
  ,  above  :: [BTStep a]   -- the subtree context of the element's node
  }  deriving (Show, Eq)
```

Annoyingly, I have to roll my own `Functor` instance.

```
instance Functor DBT where
  fmap f (DBT { above = a, below = b }) = DBT
    {  below = fmap (fmap f) b
    ,  above = fmap (f *** (either
         (Left   . (id *** fmap f))
         (Right  . (fmap f *** id)))) a  
    }
```

Now I can say what an *element* zipper is.

```
data BTZ a = BTZ
  {  here  :: a
  ,  ctxt  :: DBT a
  }  deriving (Show, Eq, Functor)
```

If you're thinking "what's new?", you're right. We have a subtree context, `above`, together with a subtree given by `here` and `below`. And that's because the only elements are those which label nodes.
Splitting a node up into an element and its context is the same as splitting it into its label and its blob of substructures. That is, we get this coincidence for cofree comonads, but not in general.

However, this coincidence is only a distraction! As we saw with lists, we don't need element-zippers to be the same as subnode-zippers to make element-zippers a comonad.

Following the same pattern as lists above, we can decorate every element with its context. The work is done by a helper function which accumulates the subtree context we are currently visiting.

```
down :: BT a -> BT (BTZ a)
down t = downIn t []

downIn :: BT a -> [BTStep a] -> BT (BTZ a)
downIn (a :& ft) ads =
  BTZ { here = a, ctxt = DBT { below = ft, above = ads } }
  :& furtherIn a ft ads
```

Note that `a` is replaced by a zipper focused on `a`. The subtrees are handled by another helper.

```
furtherIn :: a -> TF (BT a) -> [BTStep a] -> TF (BT (BTZ a))
furtherIn a Leaf           ads  = Leaf
furtherIn a (Fork (l, r))  ads  = Fork
  (  downIn l ((a, Left   ((), r)) : ads)
  ,  downIn r ((a, Right  (l, ())) : ads)
  )
```

See that `furtherIn` preserves the tree structure, but grows the subtree context suitably when it visits a subtree.

Let's double check.

```
down aTree =
  BTZ {  here  = 0, ctxt = DBT {
         below = Fork (1 :& Fork (2 :& Leaf,3 :& Leaf),4 :& Leaf),
         above = []}} :& Fork
  (  BTZ {  here = 1, ctxt = DBT {
            below = Fork (2 :& Leaf,3 :& Leaf),
            above = [(0,Left ((),4 :& Leaf))]}} :& Fork
     (  BTZ {  here = 2, ctxt = DBT {
               below = Leaf,
               above = [(1,Left ((),3 :& Leaf)),(0,Left ((),4 :& Leaf))]}} :& Leaf
     ,  BTZ {  here = 3, ctxt = DBT {
               below = Leaf,
               above = [(1,Right (2 :& Leaf,())),(0,Left ((),4 :& Leaf))]}} :& Leaf
     )
  ,  BTZ {  here = 4, ctxt = DBT {
            below = Leaf,
            above = [(0,Right (1 :& Fork (2 :& Leaf,3 :& Leaf),()))]}} :& Leaf)
```

See? Each element is decorated with its whole context, not just the tree below it.

#### Binary tree zippers form a Comonad

Now that we can decorate elements with their contexts, let us build the `Comonad` instance. As before...

```
instance Comonad BTZ where
  extract = here
```

...`extract` tells us the element in focus, and we can make use of our existing machinery to go further into the tree, but we need to build new kit to explore the ways we can move outwards.

```
  duplicate z@(BTZ { here = a, ctxt = DBT { below = ft, above = ads }}) = BTZ
    {  here = z
    ,  ctxt = DBT
         {  below = furtherIn a ft ads  -- move somewhere below a
         ,  above = go_a (a :& ft) ads  -- go above a
         }
    } where
```

To go outwards, as with lists, we must move back along the path towards the root. As with lists, each step on the path is a place we can visit.

```
    go_a t []          = []
    go_a t (ad : ads)  = go_ad t ad ads : go_a (plugBTinBT t ad) ads
    go_ad t (a, d) ads =
      (  BTZ { here = a, ctxt = DBT { below = plugF t d, above = ads } }  -- visit here
      ,  go_d t a d ads                                                   -- try other subtree
      )
```

Unlike with lists, there are alternative branches along that path to explore. Wherever the path stores an unvisited subtree, we must decorate *its* elements with *their* contexts.

```
    go_d t a (Left ((), r)) ads = Left ((), downIn r ((a, Right (t, ())) : ads))
    go_d t a (Right (l, ())) ads = Right (downIn l ((a, Left ((), t)) : ads), ())
```

So now we've explained how to refocus from any element position to any other.

Let's see. Here we were visiting `1`:

```
duplicate (BTZ {here = 1, ctxt = DBT {
                below = Fork (2 :& Leaf,3 :& Leaf),
                above = [(0,Left ((),4 :& Leaf))]}}) =
  BTZ {here = BTZ {here = 1, ctxt = DBT {
                   below = Fork (2 :& Leaf,3 :& Leaf),
                   above = [(0,Left ((),4 :& Leaf))]}}, ctxt = DBT {
       below = Fork (BTZ {here = 2, ctxt = DBT {
                          below = Leaf,
                          above = [(1,Left ((),3 :& Leaf)),(0,Left ((),4 :& Leaf))]}} :& Leaf
                    ,BTZ {here = 3, ctxt = DBT {
                          below = Leaf,
                          above = [(1,Right (2 :& Leaf,())),(0,Left ((),4 :& Leaf))]}} :& Leaf
                   ),
       above = [(BTZ {here = 0, ctxt = DBT {
                      below = Fork (1 :& Fork (2 :& Leaf,3 :& Leaf),4 :& Leaf),
                      above = []}}
                ,Left ((),BTZ {here = 4, ctxt = DBT {
                               below = Leaf,
                               above = [(0,Right (1 :& Fork (2 :& Leaf,3 :& Leaf),()))]}} :& Leaf)
                )
               ]}}
```

By way of testing the comonad laws on a small sample of data, let us check:

```
fmap (\ z -> extract (duplicate z) == z) (down aTree)
  = True :& Fork (True :& Fork (True :& Leaf,True :& Leaf),True :& Leaf)
fmap (\ z -> fmap extract (duplicate z) == z) (down aTree)
  = True :& Fork (True :& Fork (True :& Leaf,True :& Leaf),True :& Leaf)
fmap (\ z -> fmap duplicate (duplicate z) == duplicate (duplicate z)) (down aTree)
  = True :& Fork (True :& Fork (True :& Leaf,True :& Leaf),True :& Leaf)
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, I was aware there are some different kind of zippers but haven't looked into detail and your answer really make it much clear! In addition the type algebra trick looks a little magic to me but I like it. :)

Comment: Great stuff. I was a bit intrigued by your having to write that one `Functor` instance by hand, so I experimented a bit; it seems (as the error message says) the derivation generally can use only the last type argument of a type constructor; it is able to special-case tuples, but not `Either`. So if you had used the isomorphic `(Bool, a)` instead of `Either ((), t) (t, ())` it would have worked.

Comment: I'd prefer to keep the more mnemonic `Left` versus `Right` and gratuitous `()` where the "hole" is, even if I have to roll my own `fmap`. But yes, it's interesting to see what the `deriving` machinery actually does and doesn't.