# How to write this function idiomatically?

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming, filtering, higher-order-functions

I am looking for a function which tests a predicate on the elements of a list, creates a new list for each element which satisfies the predicate and applies a function only to that element.

Example:

```
someFunction :: (a -> Bool) -> (a -> a) -> [a] -> [[a]]
someFunction = ...

let ys = someFunction isOdd (* 2) [1..10]
    {- ys == [[2, 2, 3, 4, 5,  ...],
              [1, 2, 6, 4, 5,  ...],
              [1, 2, 3, 4, 10, ...],
              ...] -}
```

In `ys`, the first list is equal to the original one, except the first element, which satisfies the predicate and is multiplied by `2`. The second list is also equal to the original one, except the third element, and so on.

I have been able to write such a function by taking the indices of the values which satisfy the predicate and then mapping through the indices. However, this doesn't seem very functional and I would like to see a more idiomatic approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a finger (like a [zipper](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Zipper) :D you move your finger over each item :D as when you read)

```
someFunction :: (a -> Bool) -> (a -> a) -> [a] -> [[a]]
someFunction check f xs = r [] xs
  where r _  []     = []
        r ps (y:ys) = let rs = r (ps ++ [y]) ys
                      in  if check y then [ps ++ [f y] ++ ys] ++ rs
                                     else rs
```

`r` function take `ps` "processed elements" and `(y:ys)` "pending elements".

If you need linear cost (`ps ++ [y]` operation do it cuadratic) use efficient tail insertion struct.

Using `splitAt` you can write

```
someFunction check f xs = map (\(a,(x:b)) -> a ++ [f x] ++ b) $
                          filter (check.head.snd)
                          [splitAt n xs | n <- [0..length xs - 1]]
```

Or using list comprehension

```
someFunction check f xs =
    [ a ++ [f x] ++ b | n <- [0..length xs - 1]
                      , let (a, (x:b)) = splitAt n xs
                      , check x]
```

Using `zip` suggested by @chi the solution take linear cost (generating lists, finally is O(n^2))

```
someFunction check f xs = 
    [ a ++ [f x] ++ b | (a, (x:b)) <- init $ zip (inits xs) (tails xs)
                      , check x]
```

Finally (?) @ØrjanJohansen note to remove `init $` (I leave both versions, I think is a great example)

Avoiding `init $`

```
someFunction check f xs = 
    [ a ++ [f x] ++ b | (a, (x:b)) <- zip (inits xs) (tails xs)
                      , check x]
```

last `(xs, [])` "zipped" element is avoided by the list comprehension, @ØrjanJohansen has pointed [here](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-430003.11) how it is translated

```
[e | p <- l, Q] = let ok p = [e | Q]
                      ok _ = []
                  in concatMap ok l
```

(thx @WillNess)

Comment: A traversing lens could also be seen as a finger.

Comment: The last `zip` suggestion is essentially the idiom I would have used to write this quickly myself, but I'll just add a note that you don't need the `init $` part - the last pair is automatically filtered away by the `(a, (x:b))` pattern.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen I thought `Non-exhaustive patterns` error would be reported. Great example! Thx!

Comment: The "desugar do notation" does not work because the usually simple `do p <- e1; e2` -> `e1 >>= \p -> e2` is *not* actually the [precise official desugaring](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-470003.14) - and this case when `p` is a pattern that can fail is precisely where it breaks.

Comment: desugared list comprehension is a code using `concatMap`, not `do`... :)

Answer (score 9):

You can assemble this function from pieces which either are standard or should be. The accepted answer has the right clue about zippers. My answer [about differentiation and comonads](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25572148/828361) gives a general treatment of the relevant operations, but let me be specific here.

I define the type of "lists with one element hole" as follows:

```
data Bwd x = B0 | Bwd x :< x deriving Show
type HoleyList x = (Bwd x, [x])
```

Strictly speaking, I don't need to introduce backward lists to do that, but I get so easily confused if I have to reverse things in my head. (It so happens that `HoleyList` is the formal derivative of `[]`.)

I can now define what it is to be a list element in its context.

```
type InContext x = (HoleyList x, x)
```

The idea is that the second component of the pair belongs in between the backward list and the forward list. I can define the function which plugs the list back together (Called `upF` in the generic treatment.)

```
plug :: InContext x -> [x]
plug ((B0, xs), y)      = y : xs
plug ((xz :< x, xs), y) = plug ((xz, y : xs), x)
```

I can also define the function that gives all the ways to take a list apart (`downF`, generically).

```
selections :: [x] -> [InContext x]
selections = go B0 where
  go xz [] = []
  go xz (x : xs) = ((xz, xs), x) : go (xz :< x) xs
```

Note that

```
map snd  (selections xs) = xs 
map plug (selections xs) = map (const xs) xs
```

And now we're good to follow Bartek's recipe.

```
selectModify :: (a -> Bool) -> (a -> a) -> [a] -> [[a]]
selectModify p f = map (plug . (id *** f)) . filter (p . snd) . selections
```

That is: filter the selections by the test, apply the function to the element in focus, then plug back together. If you have the zipper equipment lying about, it's a one-liner, and it should work for any differentiable functor, not just lists! Job done!

```
> selectModify ((1 ==) . (`mod` 2)) (2*) [1..10]
[[2,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
,[1,2,6,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
,[1,2,3,4,10,6,7,8,9,10]
,[1,2,3,4,5,6,14,8,9,10]
,[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,18,10]]
```

Answer (score 5):

How about that:

Start with a list:

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

Copy the list n times, n being its size (`:: [[]]`):

```
[
 [1,2,3,4],
 [1,2,3,4],
 [1,2,3,4],
 [1,2,3,4]
]
```

Split the lists on every element (more or less "diagonally") (`:: [([], [])]`):

```
[
 ([],[1,2,3,4]),
 ([1],[2,3,4]),
 ([1,2],[3,4]),
 ([1,2,3],[4])
]
```

Filter out the lines on which `head . snd` doesn't satisfy your predicate

```
[
 ([],    [1,2,3,4]),
 ([1,2], [3,4])
]
```

Apply your function on the remaining heads

```
[
 ([],    [2,2,3,4])
 ([1,2], [6,4]),
]
```

Concatenate the pairs back

```
[
 [2,2,3,4],
 [1,2,6,4]
]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "diagonally"?

Comment: Lemme expand that a bit.

Comment: @aochagavia there you go.

Comment: Maybe it is easier to skip the copy step and directly zip inits and tails.

Answer (score 4):

Looking through all the nice and mostly somewhat fancy solutions posted here (which include @josejuan's last `zip`-based one, which is essentially the idiom I'd use myself in a hurry), I cannot help feeling the list is missing the really *direct*, but still idiomatic solution using explicit, lazy recursion - the kind of code you'd probably see in the standard libraries if `someFunction` had been a standard function.  So here's a version of that (including the `go` worker wrapping you'd also see):

```
someFunction :: (a -> Bool) -> (a -> a) -> [a] -> [[a]]
someFunction p f xs = go xs where
    go [] = []
    go (x:xs)
      | p x         = (f x : xs) : rest
      | otherwise   = rest
      where
        rest = map (x :) (go xs)
```