# Comonad duplicate function

Tags: haskell, comonad

Why when you define the function **duplicate**

```
   duplicate :: w a -> w (w a)
```

for the Comonad typeclass ([link](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/comonad-3.0.0.2/docs/Control-Comonad.html)) you have to modify all the elements "in the context" (i.e. change elements other than the *current value of the context*). Why not just use something like **return** in a Monad?

Example (zipper):

```
   data Z a = Z [a] a [a]
```

why cannot I just define duplicate as

```
   duplicate z = Z [] z []
```

I tried to derive a requirement for the **duplicate** function from the Comonad rules, but I always end up with a duplicate which just wraps the element much like a **return** in a monad without any need to do anything else.

One [blog post](http://blog.emillon.org/posts/2012-10-18-comonadic-life.html) says:

> duplicate is a bit harder to grasp. From a list zipper, we have to build a list zipper of list zippers. The signification behind this (confirmed by the comonad laws that every instance has to fulfill) is that moving inside the duplicated structure returns the original structure, altered by the same move

But I don't understand why it must be that way. The **fmap** in the Comonad rules always applies to the wrapped element and afterwards this one element is always "unwrapped" with **extract**, why bother doing anything else in the **duplicate** function other than just wrapping the argument of **duplicate**?

Can you point out what I have missed? I feel like I made some obvious error somewhere, but I just cannot figure it out on my own.

Thanks in advance for you replies!

Comment: You might be interested in this question about deriving comonad instances for zippers generically for any differentiable type. http://stackoverflow.com/q/25554062/414413 If so, check out pigworker's extensive solution with partial differential equations or my solution with a second derivative.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I scrolled over it when trying to find an answer to my question, but now when you recommended it explicitly I see it has a ton of new stuff for me to ponder over. I'll definately look into it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's important if you can do other things with the type than simply `extract` from it. Intuitively, if the only thing you can do is extract the value, then the type only holds one value, so duplicating that one value is duplicating everything. This isn't true in general, and it's not true for zippers.

The `Comonad` laws are just the category laws in disguise on functions of the type `w a -> b`. Since these come from categories, it might be easier to reason about them in terms of a category than in terms of the `Comonad` laws.  `extract` is the identity of this category and  [`=<=`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/comonad-4.2.2/docs/src/Control-Comonad.html#%3D%253c%3D) is the composition operator.

```
-- | Right-to-left 'Cokleisli' composition
(=<=) :: Comonad w => (w b -> c) -> (w a -> b) -> w a -> c
f =<= g = f . extend g
```

We also know that `extend f = fmap f . duplicate`, so we can write

```
f =<= g = f . fmap g . duplicate
```

This looks fairly easy to reason about. Now, let's equip your `Z` type with another function that we can talk about. `isFirst` will return true only when `Z` represents a value at a position in a list with nothing before it.

```
isFirst :: Z a -> Bool
isFirst (Z [] _ _) = True
isFirst  _         = False
```

Now, let's consider what happens when we use `isFirst` with the three category laws. The only two it seems are immediately applicable to it are that `extract` is a left and right identity for composition by `=<=`. Since we are only disproving this, we only need to find a counter-example. I suspect that one of `extract =<= isFirst` or `isFirst =<= extract` will fail for the input `Z [1] 2 []`. Both of these should be the same as `isFirst $ Z [1] 2 []`, which is `False`. We'll try `extract =<= isFirst` first, which happens to work out.

```
extract  =<=   isFirst               $  Z [1] 2 []
extract . fmap isFirst . duplicate   $  Z [1] 2 []
extract . fmap isFirst $ Z []          (Z [1] 2 [])  []
extract                $ Z [] (isFirst (Z [1] 2 [])) []
extract                $ Z []  False                 []
                               False
```

When we try `isFirst =<= extract` we won't be so lucky.

```
isFirst  =<=   extract               $  Z [1] 2 []
isFirst . fmap extract . duplicate   $  Z [1] 2 []
isFirst . fmap extract $ Z []          (Z [1] 2 [])  []
isFirst                $ Z [] (extract (Z [1] 2 [])) []
isFirst                $ Z []  2                     []
True
```

When we `duplicate`d we lost information about the structure. In fact, we lost information about everything that came everywhere except the single focal point of the zipper. The correct `duplicate` would have has a whole 'nother zipper everywhere in the context holding the value at that location and that location's context.

Let's see what we can deduce from these laws. With a little hand waving about the category of functions, we can see that `=<= extract` is `fmap extract . duplicate`, and this needs to be the identity function. Apparently I'm rediscovering how the laws are written in the documentation for `Control.Category`. This lets us write something like

```
z = (=<= extract)              z
z = fmap extract . duplicate $ z
```

Now, `z` has only one constructor, so we can substitute that in

```
Z left x right = fmap extract . duplicate $ Z left x right
```

From they type of duplicate, we know it must return the same constructor.

```
Z left x right = fmap extract $ Z lefts (Z l x' r) rights
```

If we apply `fmap` to this `Z` we have

```
Z left x right = Z (fmap extract lefts) (extract (Z l x' r)) (fmap extract rights)
```

If we split this up by the parts of the `Z` constructor we have three equations

```
left = fmap extract lefts
x = extract (Z l x' r)
right = fmap extract rights
```

This tells us that at the very least the result of `duplicate (Z left x right)` must hold:

- a list with the same length as `left` for the left side
- a `Z` with `x` in the middle for the middle
- a list with the same length as `right` for the right side

Furthermore, we can see that the middle values in the lists on the left and right side must be the same as the original values in those lists. Considering just this one law we know enough to demand a different structure for the result of `duplicate`.

Comment: Hi Cirdec, you nailed it. I tried to come up with a counter-example myself, but I was always targeting the focal point and I never tried to query the context (like your `isFirst` does). Not only is this the correct answer, but it contains further useful information to the topic. Upvoting and marking as accepted answer.