# Tie-the-knot in 2 dimensions (was: tying the knot with a comonad)

Tags: haskell, comonad, tying-the-knot

*Edit:* The original question was "tying the knot with a comonad", but what really helped here is a two-dimensional knot tying with `U2Graph` from [cirdec](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28521443/412549). *Original question (until Anwser):*

I want to tie the knot with data that originates from a comonad

```
data U a = U [a] a [a]
```

into a richer data structure

```
data FullCell = FullCell {
   vision   :: [[Int]],
   move     :: Int -> Maybe FullCell -- tie the knot here!
}
```

with a function

```
tieKnot :: U Int -> U FullCell
```

However, my brain encounters an "occurs check" when I try to fill in for `undefined`:

```
tieKnot :: U Int -> U FullCell
tieKnot u = u =>> (\z -> FullCell {
      vision = limitTo5x5 z,
      move = move'
})  where
         move'   1  = Just undefined -- tie the knot to neighbor here
         move' (-1) = Just undefined -- ...
         move'   _  = Nothing
         limitTo5x5 = undefined -- not of interest, but the cause why a comonad is used
```

The problem I cannot solve is, I need to refer to something I am just constructing, and it is buried deep in a comonad. And I want to be really sure that circles actually point to the same thunk.

What is the best way to solve it? Is that comonad `U a` the way to go? A doubly linked list `data T a = T (Maybe (T a)) a (Maybe (T a))` seems to run into the same problem, but will be much harder to extend to 2 dimensions.

---

Background: I try to implement [codegolf's rat race](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/44707/lab-rat-race-an-exercise-in-genetic-algorithms) in haskell. So with tying-the-know I want to refer to the same thunk owing the time-consuming computation.

## Answer

The solution comes from [Cirdec's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28521443/412549). It is just missing a small step that I do not want to squeeze into a comment.

What caused my brain to run into an "occurs check" is: To construct a `FullCell` and tie the knot on its field `move` I need the already constructed `U2Graph FullCell`. Now that I stated it, the requirement is easy to write as:

```
toU2Graph :: (U2Graph b -> a -> b) -> U2 a -> U2Graph b
```

where the first argument is a function that constructs my `FullCell`. Cirdec's function can be adapted easily. The final step is to bring the comonad back in:

```
toU2GraphW :: (U2Graph b -> U2 a -> b) -> U2 a -> U2Graph b
toU2GraphW f u = toU2Graph f (duplicate u)
```

Comment: At a glance it seems to me that "rat race" has a 2D field. How does that map to the 1D zipper?

Comment: I simplified it for Stackoverflow. I use a 2-dimensional field `U2` that [Dan Pipponi explains in the comments](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2006/12/evaluating-cellular-automata-is.html#c3054291011950765946)

Comment: I don't  know just what a comonad is or why it's important, but it seems pretty clear that you haven't included enough information in this question. 1. What does the `Comonad` instance declaration for `U` look like? 2. What knot are you trying to tie, exactly? I see now that Cirdec has (probably) read your mind and come up with an answer, but these details should be in the question.

Comment: @dfeuer The `Comonad` instance for `Zipper`s (`U` is the zipper for a list) is treated everywhere like it's well known, which means its hard to find the definition for it anywhere. I see now that there's a definition in the linked [comonad article](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2006/12/evaluating-cellular-automata-is.html) from "A Neighborhood of Infinity". I reinvented the `Comonad` instance for zippers for my answer. The [comonad instance for the zipper for a differentiable type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25554062/zipper-comonads-generically) can be derived generically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to build a graph from a zipper so that moving around on the graph doesn't require allocating new memory. This can be a performance improvement if you are going to hold on to multiple pointers into the structure.

We'll start with the zipper for lists.

```
data U a = U [a] a [a]
```

The corresponding graph holds references to the nodes to the left and right, if they exist.

```
data UGraph a = UGraph {
    _left :: Maybe (UGraph a),
    _here :: a,
    _right :: Maybe (UGraph a)
    }
```

Any instances of this structure should obey the following laws, which say that going one direction and then back the other brings you back to where you started.

```
_right >=> _left  == \x -> (_right >=> const (return x)) x
_left  >=> _right == \x -> (_left  >=> const (return x)) x
```

The `UGraph` data type doesn't enforce this, so it would be wise to put it in a module and not export the `UGraph` constructor.

To convert a zipper to a graph we start in the middle and work our way out both sides. We tie recursive knots between the already built portion of the graph and the parts of the graph that haven't already been built.

```
toUGraph :: U a -> UGraph a
toUGraph (U ls h rs) = g
    where
        g = UGraph (build ugraph' g ls) h (build UGraph g rs)
        ugraph' r h l = UGraph l h r
        build _ _    []          = Nothing
        build f prev (here:next) = Just g
            where
                g = f (Just prev) here (build f g next)
```

Combined with [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28519019/414413), you can build a graph of the visible portions of your `U Int` with

```
tieKnot :: U Int -> UGraph [[Int]]
tieKnot = toUGraph . extend limitTo5x5
```

### Two dimensions

Ultimately you want to build a 2d field. Building a graph like we did for the one dimensional list zipper in two dimensions is much trickier, and in general will require forcing `O(n^2)` memory to traverse arbitrary paths of length `n`.

You plan on using the [two-dimensional list zipper Dan Piponi described](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2006/12/evaluating-cellular-automata-is.html#c3054291011950765946), so we'll reproduce it here.

```
data U2 a = U2 (U (U a))
```

We might be tempted to make a graph for `U2` that's a straight up analog

```
data U2Graph a = U2Graph (UGraph (UGraph a))
```

This has a fairly complicated structure. Instead, we're going to do something much simpler. A node of the graph corresponding to `U2` will hold references to adjacent nodes in each of the four cardinal directions, if those nodes exist.

```
data U2Graph a = U2Graph {
    _down2  :: Maybe (U2Graph a),
    _left2  :: Maybe (U2Graph a),
    _here2  :: a,
    _right2 :: Maybe (U2Graph a),
    _up2    :: Maybe (U2Graph a)
    }
```

Instances of `U2Graph` should obey the same bidirectional iterator laws we defined for `UGraph`. Once again, the structure doesn't enforce these laws itself, so the `U2Graph` constructor probably shouldn't be exposed.

```
_right2 >=> _left2  == \x -> (_right2 >=> const (return x)) x
_left2  >=> _right2 == \x -> (_left2  >=> const (return x)) x
_up2    >=> _down2  == \x -> (_up2    >=> const (return x)) x
_down2  >=> _up2    == \x -> (_down2  >=> const (return x)) x
```

Before we convert a `U2 a` to a `U2Graph a`, let's take a look at the structure of a `U2 a`. I'm going to assign the outer list to be the left-right direction and the inner list to be the up-down direction. A `U2` has a spine going all the way across the data, with the focal point anywhere along the spine. Each sublist can be slid perpendicular to the spine so that it is focusing on a specific point on the sublist. A `U2` in the middle of use might look like the folloing. The `+`s are the outer spine, the vertical dashes `|` are the inner spines, and `*` is the focal point of the structure.

```
|
||     
|||   ||
|||| |||| |
+++*++++++++
 |||||| ||
  ||||   
   ||
```

Each of the inner spines is continuous - it can't have a gap. That means that if we are considering a location off the spine, it can only have a neighbor to the left or right if the location one closer to the spine also had a neighbor on that side. This gives rise to how we will build a `U2Graph`. We will build connections to the left and right along the outer spine, with recursive references back towards the focal point just like we did in `toUGraph`. We will build connections up and down along the inner spines, with recursive references back towards the spine, just like we did in `toUGraph`. To build the connections to the left and right from a node on an inner spine we'll move one step closer to the outer spine, move sideways at that node, and then move one step farther away from the outer spine on the adjacent inner spine.

```
toU2Graph :: U2 a -> U2Graph a
toU2Graph (U2 (U ls (U ds h us) rs)) = g
    where
        g = U2Graph (build u2down g ds) (build u2left g ls) h (build u2right g rs) (build u2up g us)
        build f _    []          = Nothing
        build f prev (here:next) = Just g
            where
                g = f (Just prev) here (build f g next)
        u2up   d h u = U2Graph d (d >>= _left2 >>= _up2  ) h (d >>= _right2 >>= _up2  ) u
        u2down u h d = U2Graph d (u >>= _left2 >>= _down2) h (u >>= _right2 >>= _down2) u
        u2left r (U ds h us) l = g
            where
                g = U2Graph (build u2down g ds) l h r (build u2up g us)
        u2right l (U ds h us) r = g
            where
                g = U2Graph (build u2down g ds) l h r (build u2up g us)
```

Comment: @dfeuer What happened to all of your interesting comments on my other answer? Perhaps they belong with this answer instead? I agree that building a graph for 2d will require forcing `O(n^2)` memory when traversing paths of length `n`. In this specific case, I believe Franky is planning on using zippers for nested lists, so there's a spine of the outer list that can be relied on to simplify what needs to be forced to the nodes between the path and the spine, which should be a small constant (about 4) times less to force than forcing a spiral.

Comment: Cirdec, I deleted them because some of them seemed non-constructive and I thought some of them might be wrong. I no longer believe O(n^2) memory will be needed for that, but I could be wrong. I'm considering using `data Ring a = Ring a a a a a a a a` (8 ྾ `a`) with `data Grid a = Grid a (Grid (Ring a))` to make a structure reminiscent of a random-access list (a la Okasaki PFDS or Hinze Numerical Representations ...). Zip to the center of a grid section, then zip out/zoom in from there. Not sure if the idea works, but I think it may give asymptotically better allocation.

Comment: That is, asymptotically better when only accessing a portion of the structure. Still working out the details, and devils lie in those.

Comment: That type I suggested is wrong, but I still think the idea makes sense. Start with a central square. Surround it with 8 squares. Now make 8 things like that and surround with them. Then repeat ad infinitum. Dealing with a finite grid will be more complicated than I can handle, so I'm attempting the case where the grid extends forever in all directions.

Comment: @Cirdec that helped a lot. For the final step, see my edited question, I do not think it that fits into a comment.

Answer (score 2):

The whole problem will be easier with the `Comonad` instance for `U`. We'll use the `Comonad` class from [comonad](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/comonad).

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}

import Data.List
import Control.Comonad

data U a = U [a] a [a]
    deriving (Functor)
```

There are two main things you can do with a zipper besides the `Comonad` methods. You can move towards the left or move towards the right. Both of these can fail if there's nothing remaining on the left or right side.

```
moveLeft :: U a -> Maybe (U a)
moveLeft (U (l:ls) h r) = Just $ U ls l (h:r)
moveLeft u              = Nothing

moveRight :: U a -> Maybe (U a)
moveRight (U l h (r:rs)) = Just $ U (h:l) r rs
moveRight u              = Nothing
```

The interesting part of `Comonad` is `duplicate :: w a -> w (w a)` which builds a structure holding the context in every location. We can define `duplicate` for the `Comonad` instance in terms of unfolding `moveLeft` and `moveRight`.

```
instance Comonad U where
    extract (U _ here _) = here
    duplicate u = U (unfoldr (fmap dup . moveLeft) u) u (unfoldr (fmap dup . moveRight) u)
        where
            dup x = (x, x)
```

We are going to tackle the problem implied by your `tieKnot`. The `duplicate` we wrote for the `Comonad` instance for `U` is going to solve all of your problems - we don't need a `FullCell` data type at all. You have some function `limitTo5x5 :: U Int -> [[Int]]`, an instance of a specific subtype of `U a -> b`.

```
limitTo5x5 :: U Int -> [[Int]]
limitTo5x5 = undefined
```

If we first `duplicate` the `U Int` we will have a zipper holding the complete context in every location. If we then `fmap limitTo5x5` over this we will have a zipper holding the results

```
tieKnot :: U Int -> U [[Int]]
tieKnot = fmap limitTo5x5 . duplicate
```

This pattern, `fmap f . duplicate`, is the `Comonad`'s dual to `Monad`s bind, `>>=`. In the `Comonad` class it's called `extend f = fmap f . duplicate`.

```
tieKnot :: U Int -> U [[Int]]
tieKnot = extend limitTo5x5
```

It's time for us to make a critical observation. When we built the outer `U` in `duplicate`, we only ever constructed a single `U _ _ _ :: U (U a)`. There's only one of them, and it doesn't recursively need to refer to anything else. We can freely move left and right along the resulting zipper without any large costs. Each time we move we need to allocate a `U` and a list cons `(:)` and simultaneously free up a `U` and a list cons.

Comment: But this doesn't tie the knot, does it? The OP explicitly stated "I want to be really sure that circles actually point to the same thunk.".

Comment: @PetrPudlák Ahh, then I will need to go further with the answer.

Comment: @PetrPudlák There's no need to tie a knot for this problem. I have edited my answer to explain why.

Comment: @Franky If what you really want to do is build a graph in memory I can write another answer for that. The two-dimensional case of building a graph is much more challenging than the one-dimensional one.