# Reasonable Comonad implementations

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, scalaz, comonad

We can describe monad, as the computational context, and monad implementation exactly preserves the meaning of that context.
For example Option - the context meaning is that the value *might* exist.
Given the Option datatype, the only implementation which makes sense is `pure = some, flatMap f = {none => none; some x => f x }`
As my understanding of monads, by following the type signatures - there is only one reasonable implementation for any monad. In other words, if you want to add some meaningful context to the value/computation, there is only one way to do it for any particular monad.

On the other hand, when it comes to comonad, it suddenly starts feeling completely strange, like there're many many ways to implement a comonad for a given type, and you might even give a certain meaning for every implementation.

Consider, NEL, with `copure = head`.  `cojoin` is implemented via `tails`, which perfectly satisfies the types. If we implement `cojoin` by `permutations` or as `fa map (_ => fa) map f` it will not satisfy comonad laws. 
 But *circling* implementation is valid:

```
override def cobind[A, B](fa: NonEmptyList[A])(f: (NonEmptyList[A]) => B): NonEmptyList[B] = {
  val n: NonEmptyList[NonEmptyList[A]] = fa.map(_ => fa).zipWithIndex.map { case (li , i ) =>
    val(h: List[A], t: List[A]) = li.list.splitAt(i)
    val ll: List[A] = t ++ h
    NonEmptyList.nel(ll.head, ll.tail)
  }
  n map f
}
```

The reason of such ambiguity for Command, even with having the laws restricting us, as I see it, that if in Monad we restrict ourselves in some context (we kind of can't “create" new information), in Comonad, we are extending that context further( there are quite a ways to make a List of Lists from List), which gives us a way more possibilities of doing it. In my head metaphor is: for Monad, we are standing on the road and want reach some destination point A = hence there’re only meaningful shortest way to chose. In command, we are standing in A, and wanna go somewhere from it, so there’re way more ways of doing it. 
So my question is -  am I actually right? Can we implement command in a different ways, every time making another meaningful abstraction? Or only *tails* implemantation is reasonable beacause of the abstraction comonad supposes to bring in.

Comment: It is incorrect to presume that a given type operator has at most one monad implementation. For example, pairing with a Boolean has at least as many monad implementations as there are monoids on Booleans, so and, or, exclusive-or, equality all give different monads. Tarmo Uustalu gives a very beautiful combinatorial treatment of this issue, enumerating the possible (co)monad structures for a given container-like type operator. The key is indeed to identify the monoid structures on the underlying "shapes and positions" of the container. These tend to be far from unique.

Comment: Thanks! Does that mean that any Monad/Comonad implementation which satisfies laws makes sense? And why then, for instance, "default" Nel cobind implementation is via tails?

Comment: @ISeeVoices "makes sense" doesn't have a meaning.  Any monad/comonad that satisfy the laws has certain given properties, period.  Whether you can make use of these properties and exploit them to obtain something useful is an other matter that depends on what you are dealing with and what you want to achieve but there's no way to formally define "useful monad" or "useful comonad".  The default implementation were chosen by the developers of the language based on their *opinion* of which one is more useful; opinion which hopefully is based on real life experiences of using the instances.

Comment: @pigworker do you have a citation on the Uustalu paper?

Comment: @sclv Start [here](http://cs.ioc.ee/~tarmo/ssgep15/) and follow your nose.

Answer (score 8):

Nonempty lists arise as two distinct comonads by two standard constructions.

Firstly, the *cofree comonad* is given thus.

```
data Cofree f x = x :& f (Cofree f x)  -- every node is labelled with an x

instance Functor f => Functor (Cofree f) where
  fmap f (x :& fcx) = f x :& fmap (fmap f) fcx

instance Functor f => Comonad (Cofree f) where
  extract (x :& _) = x   -- get the label of the top node
  duplicate cx@(_ :& fcx) = cx :& fmap duplicate fcx
```

Nonempty lists can be given as

```
type Nellist1 = Cofree Maybe
```

and are thus automatically comonadic. That gives you the "tails" comonad.

Meanwhile, the decomposition of a structure as an "element zipper" induces comonadic structure. As I [explained at great length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25554062/zipper-comonads-generically),

Differentiability amounts to this bunch of operations on zippers (individual elements picked out of their context and put "in focus")

```
class (Functor f, Functor (DF f)) => Diff1 f where
  type DF f :: * -> *
  upF      ::  ZF f x  ->  f x           -- defocus
  downF    ::  f x     ->  f (ZF f x)    -- find all ways to focus
  aroundF  ::  ZF f x  ->  ZF f (ZF f x) -- find all ways to *re*focus

data ZF f x = (:<-:) {cxF :: DF f x, elF :: x}
```

so we get a functor and a comonad

```
instance Diff1 f => Functor (ZF f) where
  fmap f (df :<-: x) = fmap f df :<-: f x

instance Diff1 f => Comonad (ZF f) where
  extract    = elF
  duplicate  = aroundF
```

In principle, nonempty lists arise by this construction, too. The trouble is that the functor being differentiated is not so easy to express in Haskell, even though the derivative is sensible. Let's go nuts...

Nonempty lists amount to `ZF thingy x` where `DF thingy = []`. Can we integrate lists? Fooling about algebraically might give us a clue

```
[x] = Either () (x, [x]) = 1 + x * [x]
```

so as a power series, we get

```
[x] = Sum(n :: Nat). x^n
```

and we can integrate power series

```
Integral [x] dx = Sum(n :: Nat). x^(n+1)/(n+1)
```

which means we get some sort of arbitrary tuples of size (n+1), but we have to identify them up to some relation where the equivalence classes have size (n+1). One way to do that is to identify tuples up to rotation, so you don't know which of the (n+1) positions is "first".

That is, lists are the derivative of nonempty cycles. Think about a bunch of people at a round table playing cards (possibly solitaire). Rotate the table and you get the same bunch of people playing cards. But once you designate the *dealer*, you fix the list of other players in order, clockwise starting left of the dealer.

Two standard constructions; two comonads for the same functor.

(In my comment earlier, I remarked about the possibility of multiple monads. It's a bit involved, but here's a starting point. Every monad `m` is also applicative, and the applicative laws make `m ()` a monoid. Correspondingly, every monoid structure for `m ()` at least gives a candidate for a monad structure on `m`. In the case of writer monads `(,) s`, we get that the candidates for monads are the monoids on `(s,())` which are just the same as the monoids on `s`.)

**Edit** Nonempty lists are also *monadic* in at least two distinct ways.

I define the identity and pairing for functors, as follows.

```
newtype I         x = I x
data    (f :*: g) x = (:&:) {lll :: f x, rrr :: g x}
```

Now, I can introduce nonempty lists as follows, then define concatenation.

```
newtype Ne x = Ne ((I :*: []) x)

cat :: Ne x -> Ne x -> Ne x
cat (Ne (I x :&: xs)) (Ne (I y :&: ys)) = Ne (I x :&: (xs ++ y : ys))
```

These are monadic just the way possibly empty lists are:

```
instance Monad Ne where
  return x = Ne (I x :&: [])
  Ne (I x :&: xs) >>= k = foldl cat (k x) (map k xs)
```

However, `I` is a monad:

```
instance Monad I where
  return = I
  I a >>= k = k a
```

Moreover, monads are closed under pairing:

```
instance (Monad f, Monad g) => Monad (f :*: g) where
  return x = return x :&: return x
  (fa :&: ga) >>= k = (fa >>= (lll . k)) :&: (ga >>= (rrr . k))
```

So we could just have written

```
newtype Ne x = Ne ((I :*: []) x) deriving (Monad, Applicative, Functor)
```

but the `return` for that monad gives us double vision.

```
return x = Ne (I x :&: [x])
```

So there you are: nonempty lists are comonadic two ways, monadic two ways, applicative six ways,...

(Lots more to say about this, but I have to stop somewhere.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the same counterexample, showing that a Monad has multiple possible instances, from pigworker's comment, but more worked through (though not typechecked, so pardon any errors).

```
data WithBool a = WB Bool a deriving Functor

instance Monad WithBool where
     return = WB z
     (WithBool b a) >>= f =
           case f a of (WithBool b2 r) -> WithBool (b `op` b2) r

-- This holds if op = (&&) and z = True
-- This also holds if op = (||) and z = False
-- It should also work if op = const or `flip const` and z = True _or_ False
```

As Bakuriu says, the choice of a "default" implementation is thus somewhat arbitrary, and conditioned by what people are expected to want.

Comment: thanks everyone, now this is a bit more clear. So, laws guarantee us certain behaviour, but the meaning of our implementation we should find ouselves.